# converting a normal string into a json array by including square brackets and double qoutes

Tags: jquery, json

I've a string: `var textData = $('#textare').val();`

where `textData` content is --> `changed by arunesh,changed by avi`

I want to convert it like --> `["changed by arunesh","changed by avi"]`, like  a json array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// it will make it an array.
var arr = $('#textare').val().split(',');
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin , that was easy , solved my problem ..i was thinking i need some json library to do so.